# Category Template for custom posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, wp-list-categories

Hi I would like to use category-(slug).php for my custom post type.

In functions.php I have defined the movies post type as following

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_movie' );
function create_post_type_movie() {
register_post_type( 'ra_movie',
array(
  'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
  ),
  'public' => true,
  'has_archive' =>true,
  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movie'),
  'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments','custom-fields','revisions'),
  'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag') // this is IMPORTANT
));
}
```

So the slug of teh post type is **movie**. when I load

../category-movie/design

it displays the 404. I am using wordpress 3.5.1 so it should be able to display category-(slug).php

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: what excatly you wanna do display your single custom post right?

Comment: make a file single-ra_movie.php and make your custom post on the backend and view the post